# struct for nested dictionary API in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, api

i'm trying to import JSON data from the v2 of coinmarketcap API. I had it working with v1 as it was an array, however the new version is a dictionary and i cant quite get my struct correct.
The API im using is : https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=AUD

My struct is set up as below:

```
struct Coin: Decodable {
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "rank", symbol, name, priceAUD = "quotes"
}
var id: String
var symbol : String
var name : String
var priceAUD : quoteStruct

}

struct quoteStruct{
    let aud : priceStruct
}

struct priceStruct{
    let price : String
}
```

My code for fetching the data is:

```
var coins = [Coin]()

func getCoinData() {
    let jsonURL = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=AUD"
    let url = URL(string: jsonURL)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { [unowned self] (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            self.coins = try JSONDecoder().decode([Coin].self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        } catch {
            print("Error is : \n\(error)")
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

My code for fetching the data i have used the same as previously which worked with v1 of the API, however i don't think i made my struct correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The JSON is a Dictionary, not an Array. The "first" key is `data`, which doesn't appear at all in your parsing. How do you expect it to work? Because `[Coin].self` that's saying you'll have an array of `Coin`, but that's not the case. Your struct doesn't mimic the JSON one.

Comment: You data should be an `array` rather than a `dictionary`. How can you iterate a dictionary over undefined keys?. It would be good to get your response of API updated first.

Comment: thanks guys, i better do some more research into parsing from dictionary's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You response in `data` parameter should be an array rather than a dictionary. You will not be able to iterate a dictionary over undefined keys. It would be good to get your response of API updated first.

**But, If you wish to continue with the existing API response, first you need to convert your response in an array and use your `Decodable` structs as:**

```
struct Coin: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var symbol : String
    var name : String
    var priceAUD : QuoteStruct

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "rank", symbol, name, priceAUD = "quotes"
    }
}

struct QuoteStruct: Decodable {
    let aud : PriceStruct
}

struct PriceStruct: Decodable {
    let price : String
}
```

**Update your data parsing in API block as:**

```
    guard let responseData = data else { return }
    do {
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])
        if let jsonData = json as? [String: Any], let dataObject = jsonData["data"] as? [Int: Any] {
            let coinArray = dataObject.map { $0.1 }

            if let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: coinArray, options: .prettyPrinted) {
                coins = try JSONDecoder().decode([Coin].self, from: jsonData)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error is : \n\(error)")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works very well and without requiring me to overly restructure my whole project :)

Comment: Welcome @SeanSlack.

Answer (score 2):

Your response Changed i try to configure it by converting it to array of dictionary you will need to change  `quotes` to be `[String:priceStruct`]

```
struct Coin: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id,rank,symbol, name, priceAUD = "quotes"
    }
    var id: Int
    var rank: Int
    var symbol : String
    var name : String
    var priceAUD : [String: priceStruct]

}

struct priceStruct : Decodable{
    let price : Double
}

 func getCoinData() {
         var coins = [Coin]()
        let jsonURL = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=AUD"
        let url = URL(string: jsonURL)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { [unowned self] (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                 if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any], let resultData = json["data"]  as? [String:Any] {

                     let dataObject = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: resultData.values.map({$0})  , options: .prettyPrinted)
                    coins = try JSONDecoder().decode([Coin].self, from: dataObject)
                    print(coins.count)

                  }



            } catch {
                print("Error is : \n\(error)")
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```